# How to evaluate this factorial-related integral?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function, multiple-integral

I came up with an unusual integral at the bottom of the page when tried to find a closed form for this factorial-related integral:

$$\boxed{\int_0^1 \Gamma(t+1) \text{ d}t = 0.92274\ldots}$$

Here is what I did:

$$
\boxed{\textbf{I}=\int_0^1 \Gamma(t+1) \text{ d}t} \\
t\in(0,1) \Rightarrow \Gamma(t+1)= \int_0^1 (-\ln(s))^t \text{ d}s \\
=\int_0^1\int_0^1 (-\ln(s))^t\text{ d}s \text{ d}t \\
=\int_0^1\int_0^1(-\ln(s))^t\text{ d}t \text{ d}s \\
=\int_0^1\frac{-\ln(s)-1}{\ln(-\ln(s))}\text{ d}s, \\ \textbf{Substitution: }u=-\ln(s), \\
=\int_\infty^0 \frac{u-1}{-e^u\ln(u)}\text{ d}u \\
=\int_0^\infty \frac{u-1}{e^u\ln(u)} \text{ d}u
$$

How can I continue now? Although this integral doesnt seem to be very complicated, i could not come up with a closed form or series representation. Neither did Wolframalpha.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Ummm... isn't this $\int\limits_{t=1}^2 \Gamma(t)\ dt$??

Comment: Idea **no** exist yet. **No** closed-form with special function and elementary function.